# react Passing Data Between React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react page i'm building a html table. table rows are generated from a child component as follows **'ViewGRNTable'**.
 Upto this page is working great 
also i want to get a value from every row in child component and add it to the 'this.state.GRNtotal'. for that I wrote a callback function 'callbackRowSum' which returns 'rowsum' and add value it to this.state.GRNtotal

```
    ViewGRNCartTableRow(){
        return this.state.cartProducts.map(function(object,i){
            return <ViewGRNTable obj={object} key={i} callbackSum = {this.callbackRowSum} />;
        });
    }
    callbackRowSum = (rowsum) => {
        this.setState({GRNtotal: this.state.GRNtotal+rowsum})
    }
```

but it gives an error 
TypeError: Unable to get property 'callbackRowSum' of undefined or null reference
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a binding issue, change your function for an arrow function

```
ViewGRNCartTableRow(){
  return this.state.cartProducts.map((object,i) => (
    <ViewGRNTable
      obj={object}
      key={i}
      callbackSum={this.callbackRowSum}
    />
  ));
}
```

It's because you're not binding the `this` keyword to the function being passed to `map`, you can solve that easily with the arrow function or you can manually bind your function like this

```
ViewGRNCartTableRow(){
  return this.state.cartProducts.map(function(object,i){
    return (
      <ViewGRNTable
        obj={object}
        key={i}
        callbackSum={this.callbackRowSum}
      />
    );
  }.bind(this));
}
```